# Which DNSExit client to download for Natty (11.04)? Rpm or Deb?

Tags: 11.04, deb, dns, tar, rpm

I have an [Ubuntu 11.04 server](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-11.04-ispconfig-3) set up to host some websites and I have a dynamic IP address.  I am using [DNSExit.com](http://www.dnsexit.com) to handle the DNS routing to the IP address and would like to install their [DNS client](http://www.dnsexit.com/Direct.sv?cmd=userIpClients) on my system, so whenever the IP address changes, it will automatically update their records.

The client comes in three flavors and I do not know which to install.  They are all the same version (1.6-2).

[image: DNSExit Client]

Also, are the installation commands that they have on the page accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the .deb package. Simply double click the downloaded file and the ubuntu software center will appear. Wait a moment and you are able to click on "install".

Comment: Thanks!  Can you please refer me to any docs/resources which explain why we must use the .deb package?  Also, the server doesn't have a UI, which is why I was curious about the validity of the given commands.

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian Linux. Here are some basics about deb-packages: http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html